# Check column for variable and get value from another column in matched row

Tags: python, loops, csv, multiple-columns

How can I get the values of one column in a csv-file by matching attributes in another column?

CSV-file would look like that:

```
One,Two,Three
x,car,5
x,bus,7
x,car,9
x,car,6
```

I only want to get the values of column 3, if they have the value "car" in column 2. I also do not want them to be added but rather have them printed in a list, or like that:

```
5
9
6
```

My approach is looking like that, but doesn't really work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"example.csv")

ITEMS = [car] #I will need more items, this is just examplified

for item in df.Two:
    if item in ITEMS:
        print(df.Three)
```

How can I get the exact value for a matched item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line you can do it like:

```py
print(df['Three'][df['Two']=='car'].values)
```

Output:

```
[5 9 6]
```

For multiple items try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'One': ['x','x','x','x', 'x'],'Two': ['car','bus','car','car','jeep'],'Three': [5,7,9,6,10]})

myitems = ['car', 'bus']
res_list = []

for item in myitems:
    res_list += df['Three'][df['Two']==item].values.tolist()

print(*sorted(res_list), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
5
6
7
9
```

**Explanation**

1. `df['Two']=='car'` returns a Dataframe with boolean `True` at row positions where value in column **Two** of of `df` is **car**
2. `.values` gets these boolean values as a `numpy.ndarray`, result would be `[True False  True  True]`
3. We can filter the values in column **Three** by using this list of booleans like so: `df['Three'][<Boolean_list>]`
4. To combine the resulting arrays we convert each `numpy.ndarray` to python `list` using `tolist()` and append it to `res_list`
5. Then we use `sorted` to sort `res_list`

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to insert the ITEMS list into this? Is there a way to do that? Imagine the ITEMS list consisting of more than 1, maybe 100 items..

Comment: I've updated the answer, I'll add an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the update - this actually works, but different than imagined, as it will put out a list for each item individually - again, is there a way to have values of column Three in order, regardless of what item they match? Imagine those values being an increasing amount and I need to have them in an increasing order! Sorry if I am asking for too much

Comment: Do you want the resulting lists to be combined and  sort them in increasing order? I did not understand the request.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it! In my case, the values are not random, but increasing with the row, and for my ongoing calculations they would need to be in order